# Query multiple tables (2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, communication

I have 2 tables in one database: first has an information about apatrments, second show what apartments have already booked: has ApatrmentIds from first one, and 2 dates: arrive and departure.

I need to show users what apartments are available to book. It means that user inputs date and apartments dates of book don't match.

Model of first table:

```
        public class Apartment
        {

            public int ApartmentId { get; set;}

            [Required]
            public int Quantity { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public Classes Class { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int Price { get; set; }

        }

        public enum Classes
        {
            Economy,
            Standart,
            Luxury
        }
```

Model of second table:

```
  public class Booked
    {
        public int BookedId { get; set;}

        public int ApartmentId { get; set; }

        public DateTime Start { get; set; }

        public DateTime End { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to use linq, but i need to communicate between ApartmentId(key) of the first table and ApartmentId(not key) of the second.

How it would be better to do?

Comment: Do you really mean different databases or do you mean tables in the same database? What you are showing looks like different tables but you keep mentioning databases. Often these terms can be confusing to those just starting to learn relational database / database design.

Comment: @Igor, sorry i mean diffrent tables in one database

Comment: That is a *very* big difference. What you are looking for is called a "table join", you can also search on entity relationships when searching for Entity Framework solutions. There is a lot of material out there on how to structure these relationships and how to query them.

Comment: @Igor, yes, i understand that it's a very big diffrence, so what do you think is better to fixed it?

Comment: `so what do you think is better to fixed it` ← Research. Again, there is *a lot* of material out there including *many* tutorials and relationships is usually covered early on in any of these sites. All you have to do is spend a little time reading. The above problem can be solved with a trivial amount of effort on your part.

Comment: You can refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593227/linq-query-with-multiple-tables-and-extracting-data